# passing command line parameter to spring config

Tags: java, spring

I want to laod the spring context file based on the command line. Basically I am going to get the region from the command line and instanciate the beans in the context file based on region. Is there a way to pass the command line param to `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` without maintaining 2 different context files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it depends on where exactly you want to load it:

- use `<import resource="${command.line.param}/context.xml" />` in your common `applicationContext.xml`
- use `<param-value>${command.line.param}/applicationContext.xml</param-value>` in your web.xml, in a `context-param` named `contextConfigLocation`